# The Name for $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{O}$ Exclusively Algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, terminology

The Wikipedia page for [Normed Division Algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Normed_division_algebra&redirect=no) has been redirected to Normed Algebras and [the explanation given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Normed_division_algebra) is that $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{O}$ algebras are not the only normed division algebras.

What is the name for the class of algebras consisting of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{O}$ exclusively?

Comment: For future reference, standard mathematical syntax is \mathbb for real and complex numbers (same goes for quaternions and octonions I guess?).

Comment: I guess "finite-dimensional normed unital division algebra" (maybe with a permutation on the first few words). Or maybe "$\{\mathbb{R,C,H,O}\}$".

Comment: That wikipedia page suggests you should say "normed division algebras with unity".  Unless, of course, your definition of "algebra" includes "with unity" already.

Comment: @GEdgar: Does "division algebra" have a sense in the non-unital context?  Does it just mean that multiplication by any non-zero element is a bijection?  In the associative case I guess this automatically implies that there is a unity. I've never thought about the alternating case, though (or the general non-associative context).

Comment: "Normed division Cayley–Dickson algebras"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call them the **real [composition algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_algebra)**.  The result that states they are the only four is called [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras)#Classification), and in Jacobson's *Basic algebra I* you can find the generalized version which applies to fields beyond $\Bbb R$.

The definition of a composition algebra is basically "a nonassociative unital algebra with a nondegenerate bilinar form making a norm." I thought I remember elsewhere some characterization in terms of an involution too, but I'm sticking with Jacobson's definition for now.

---

Please note also that the comment you linked to about the theorem being "incorrect" is not really anything to pay attention to. The author takes a minority stance that the inclusion of identity is not assumed. However, it is assumed for all statements of the Hurwitz theorem that I've seen. There is no shortage of such comments on wikipedia, which is why you have to be careful what you believe :)

Comment: The nice thing about calling them "Euclidean Hurwitz Algebras" is that by naming them for the theorem that identifies the set {$\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{O}$} one is providing a formal definition that is not subject to misunderstandings.

Comment: Dear @JamesBowery : I don't see any tangible advantage of "Euclidean Hurwitz" over "real composition." Both of them require more knowledge than what appears in the names. Objectively, they are pretty much fungible, except for that the latter generates more google hits online. On second thought, "Euclidean" and "composition" are not nearly as helpful as "real" and "Hurwitz," so I rather quite like the sound of "real Hurwitz algebra." That's all well and good, but I'll still defer to the one that generates more hits.

Comment: OK, without objection I'll call yours the correct answer.  Indeed, it _is_ better to have a name that is most widely used by people with {$\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{O}$ } in mind as long as it isn't formally misleading (except according to a few Wikipedian pedants).

Answer (score 0):

[Euclidean Hurwitz algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras)#Classification)

"Theorem. The only Euclidean Hurwitz algebras are the real numbers, the complex numbers, the quaternions and the octonions."

Answer (score -1):

This list of algebras stems from the [Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)) for finite division algebras over the real numbers. As one goes further down the list, properties of the real numbers are lost along the way.

1. Real numbers: totally ordered, commutative, associative
2. Complex numbers: commutative, associative
3. Quaternions: associative
4. Octonions: none of the above

Comment: The Frobenius theorem leaves out $\mathbb{O}$.

Comment: ... and everything after the first sentence is off-topic, although frequently discussed on the site and interesting in itself.